# Не получается зайти в брейкпоинт при настройке [Route]. Маршрутизация

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, route, asp-net-core-mvc

Нужно отправить get-запрос через postman, чтобы внутри данного метода сработал брейкпонит и я убедился что все работает, я отправляю данный get запрос:
http://localhost:49391/api/WeatherForecast/GetRedirectGatewayUrl/client_id=2&scope=open%file

Не могу ничего отловить и не понимаю в чем проблема

Код ниже:

```
        [Route("api/account/GetRedirectEsiaGatewayUrl/{esiaConfirmationLevelType}/{querystring}")]
        [HttpGet(nameof(GetRedirectEsiaGatewayUrl) + "/{esiaConfirmationLevelType}/{querystring}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetRedirectEsiaGatewayUrl(EsiaConfirmationLevelType esiaConfirmationLevelType, string querystring)
        {
            
           // код в методе
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Глупая проблема в том что у меня был записан "api/account/GetRedirectGatewayUrl/,а надо "GetRedirectGatewayUrl"
и в итоге отправлялось как "api/account/api/account/GetRedirectEsiaGatewayUrl"